# Axis2 and Spring

Tags: apache-axis

I would like to create webservice module under maven project with service/dao/web all using spring framework. Is there a way Axis2 can along with Spring and JWS annotation? Do I need to include services.xml?
Can I bundle this module as jar and deploy as a part of war similar to other modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by following below steps.

- Create dynamic web project using apache axis 2 framework in eclipse.
- Convert this project into Maven project and add Spring dependencies(Spring beans,core,context and web) to maven.
- create ApplicationContext.xml file under WEB-INF.
- Add context file reference to web.xml.
- Modify services.xml, add below parameters to service description.

  ```
  <parameter name="SpringBeanName"> your service bean name </parameter>
  <parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier</parameter>
  ```
- Add Service bean in ApplicationContext.xml

  ```
  <bean name="your service bean name" class="fully qualified class name"></bean>
  ```

Now in your service bean you can use spring services using annotations and giving bean definitions in application context.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, see links above:

- http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/pojoguide.html
- http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html